# How to add comments box facebook to web browser windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, facebook-comments

How way to add comment box facebook to web browser on windows phone. I tried embeded code from [comments box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) to webbrowser

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=163259763856921";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it don't display anything. Can you help me?